# H2 jdbc Connection refused: connect 90067-147

Tags: java, database, jdbc, h2, h2db

I got a project to upgrade and it is using h2 DB with jdbc driver. During the build I have a systematic error on connection:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "Connection refused: connect" [90067-147]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:156)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:380)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:271)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.createSession(SessionRemote.java:265)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:110)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:94)
at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

I don't see why the connection is refused, the server is well started on the same URL, PORT and DB as the one requested.

The server is well started, but the error happen when I want to open the connection:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPWD + " " + DB_PWD);
```

Any idea about what can be the cause?

Update: This problem was not related to the firewalls but mainly to the server DB path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can be the reasons of connection refused errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333400/what-can-be-the-reasons-of-connection-refused-errors)

Comment: Can you please share the entire stack trace? Are there any others except this one? What does *systematic* mean in this context, does the error occur constantly or does the exception occur consistently at specific intervals of time?

Comment: According to the error code `90067-147`, you are using a very old version of H2: version 1.2.147 from 2010-11-21. You should upgrade to a more recent version.

Comment: I upgraded the version, error now is :Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-189]

Comment: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)

Comment: at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:122)
 at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:102)
 at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:114)
 at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:448)

Comment: I'm using this path for the server start: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9095/testdb;CIPHER=AES;IFEXISTS=TRUE

Comment: Problem solved, the version update was a good step, I found an issue with the db path, I update it //localhost/./testdb and now everything is ok. Thanks all.

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue.  I am Spring beginner and I do not understand how you solved the problem.  Could you explain please?