# Raspberry Pi SSH connection over Ethernet fails

Tags: windows, ssh, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I'm trying to establish a connection over SSH from my Win 8.1 laptop to my raspberry pi 3 model B as the host. Connecting over wifi works flawlessly each time, however I need to demo projects in class and the campus wifi does not play well with SSH, our professor stated that we must use an Ethernet connection. I have tried both putty and Bitvise SSH clients with same results - either "connection refused" or "no connection could be made because the machine actively refused it".

I have tried:

- Enabling internet sharing on the Ethernet connection and enabling the SSH services (port 22 both TCP and UDP)
- Disabling wifi on Win
- Forgetting wifi on raspberry
- Manually activating SSH server on raspberry even though I'm pretty sure it was activated already.
- Deleting SSH keys from the wifi sessions
- Completely disabling the firewall
- `ipconfig /release` `ipconfig /renew`
- Restarting both machines after every of the above
- Reimaging memory card with newest Raspbian

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** The link [What can be the reasons of connection refused errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333400/what-can-be-the-reasons-of-connection-refused-errors) did not help, the listed reasons are closed ports or firewall and as I already said I tried to open the required ports through the shared Ethernet connection and turned off Windows firewall completely with no other firewall programs running. From my understanding Raspbian doesn't come with any enabled firewalls and allows all traffic. Can someone correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can be the reasons of connection refused errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333400/what-can-be-the-reasons-of-connection-refused-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a guide that works: http://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-connect-to-a-raspberry-pi-directly-with-an-ethernet-cable/

The crucial step was to set the static IP address of the pi to my laptop's Ethernet adapter address but modify the last part. You're welcome, all you poor souls from the future.