# Connection to remote machine via telnet failed with "Connection refused"

Tags: ssh, telnet

I have two VMs centos 7 minimal installation, for each machine I added new additional network adapter configure IP and put the new hostname + IP in the /etc/hosts on both nodes.

Here you can see the new network adapters: 172.17.235.75-rvpcmk01-cr and 172.17.235.106-rvpcmk02-cr

When I trying to do telnet from node 2 to node 1 I failed (the opposite works o.k).

```
[root@rvpcmk01 HARADview]# telnet rvpcmk02-cr 2224
Trying 172.17.235.106…
Connected to rvpcmk02-cr.
Escape character is ‘^]’.
When perform it from node2 to node1 I got Connection refused:
[root@rvpcmk02 ~]# telnet rvpcmk01-cr 2224
Trying 172.17.235.75…
telnet: connect to address 172.17.235.75: Connection refused



[root@rvpcmk02 ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
172.17.235.43 rvpcmk01
172.17.235.44 rvpcmk02
172.17.235.75 rvpcmk01-cr
172.17.235.106 rvpcmk02-cr


[root@rvpcmk01 ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

172.17.235.43 rvpcmk01
172.17.235.44 rvpcmk02
172.17.235.75 rvpcmk01-cr
172.17.235.106 rvpcmk02-cr
```

Comment: Is the telnet server listening on port 2224? What does "netstat -a -n | grep 2224" say on rvpcmk01-cr?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can be the reasons of connection refused errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333400/what-can-be-the-reasons-of-connection-refused-errors)

Comment: "netstat -a -n | grep 2224" output nothing