# Issue while accessing registry deployed in Kubernetes from Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, kubernetes, registry, docker-desktop

I am running Docker Desktop on W10 to try Camel-k. Camel-K required a repository to push the images, once it completed build in Kubernetes platform. I don't want docker.io to be configured, so deployed docker registry in Kubernetes running on top of Docker Desktop.

Deployed: https://github.com/Joxit/docker-registry-ui/tree/master/examples/helm/docker-registry-ui

```
**kubectl get pod:**
private-registry-registry-docker-registry-ui-69bdb85647-rmvhs

private-registry-ui-docker-registry-ui-6f49d78f58-d6qqt
```

**updating docker deamon.js**

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
   "insecure-registries" : [
      "private-registry-registry-docker-registry-ui:5000"
    ],
   "debug" : true,
   "experimental": true
}
```

**Adding host entry:**

```
127.0.0.1 private-registry-registry-docker-registry-ui
```

**Kubectl port-forward** to access port 5000:

```
kubectl port-forward private-registry-registry-docker-registry-ui-69bdb85647-rmvhs 5000:5000
```

**pushing an image**

```
docker tag alpine:latest private-registry-registry-docker-registry-ui:5000/alpine:latest

docker push private-registry-registry-docker-registry-ui:5000/alpine:latest

The push refers to repository [private-registry-registry-docker-registry-ui:5000/alpine]
***Get http://private-registry-registry-docker-registry-ui:5000/v2/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused***
```

Does anyone faced similar issue while accessing registry deployed in Kubernetes? Please suggest what's needs to be done in order to fix this problem. I found similar problem for Docker Desktop mac and have tried but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your docker **deamon.js** should look like this:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
   "insecure-registries" : [
      "localhost:5000",
      "127.0.0.1:5000",
      "private-registry-registry-docker-registry-ui:5000"
    ],
   "debug" : true,
   "experimental": true
}
```

When you want to add insecure registry after updating **docker deamon.js** you have to restart docker. Make sure you have done this. Make sure that port 5000 is open on destination machine. Also check firewalls.

Speaking about pushing image, I think you don't have a **default** registry. You have to:

1. Start the registry container 
   `$ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2`

Check the `registry` container is running, execute command:  `$ docker ps | grep registry`, and then proceed further - tag and push your image.

2. Tag your image (`$ docker tag ...` )
3. Push your image using command (`$ docker push ...`)

Take a look on similar problems: [docker-push-issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3611), [connection-refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698748/connection-refused-on-pushing-a-docker-image).

Comment: This is still failing, the other way round is working. Means, docker default registry running  using docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2. using Virtual Eternet IPv4 address, same registry is accessible from Kubernetes cluster, which Camel-K Buildah able to push the image to repository. 

Thanks for the update.