# Unable to push images to the docker-registry using the kubectl plugin

Tags: kubernetes, centos7, docker-registry

I'm a fresher when it comes to using kubernetes. Please help me with the issue I am facing.
I am trying to push the images to the local docker-registry. Some of the images are being pushed successfully, but in a couple of seconds it is failing. It is giving me this error message:

```
{"status":"The push refers to repository [docker-registry:30001/netapp/astracc/22.08.1-26/graphql-server]"}
{"errorDetail":{"message":"Get "https://docker-registry:30001/v2/\": dial tcp 192.168.0.96:30001: connect: connection refused"},"error":"Get "https://docker-registry:30001/v2/\": dial tcp 192.168.0.96:30001: connect: connection refused"}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkfS2.png)

I tried creating a new docker-registry and making sure that the docker is running but the issue still occurs.

This is the output to check if my registry is up and running:

[root@kubmas2 acc]# docker ps | grep registry

ab05d3e41abf   registry                                                "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute             k8s_registry_docker-registry-547576f64c-9w8rl_registry_b48428e8-4b45-422f-906c-37c6c6286f80_0

d59cab9271fc   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6                                    "/pause"                 About a minute ago   Up About a minute             k8s_POD_docker-registry-547576f64c-9w8rl_registry_b48428e8-4b45-422f-906c-37c6c6286f80_0

f40fdeae0b7c   registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/csi-node-driver-registrar   "/csi-node-driver-re…"   8 days ago           Up 8 days                     k8s_driver-registrar_trident-csi-nxhxb_trident_6245b9f7-205a-463a-bb7b-0d15a08b5189_0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZKFJ.png)

Comment: Based on this; https://stackoverflow.com/a/52699117/8658598 can you check if your registry container is actually running?

Comment: I ran the command based on the link on your comment. This is the output I get:

cf7d4b90302c   registry                                                "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   19 hours ago   Up 19 hours             k8s_registry_docker-registry-547576f64c-vqsz6_registry_0937061b-a538-4bba-952d-21539a8bbc19_0

93ce12c3d197   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6                                    "/pause"                 19 hours ago   Up 19 hours             k8s_POD_docker-registry-547576f64c-vqsz6_registry_0937061b-a538-4bba-952d-21539a8bbc19_0

Comment: Could you add that output in the original question so others can see registry is up and running.

Comment: I added the output to the original post

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the text of the messages rather than links to image files?  How are you actually pushing the images (I might normally expect to use `docker push` and not a Kubernetes command)?  Is this a programming-related question, or about trying to configure a registry server?

Comment: I am trying to push the astra images to the docker-registry using a kubectl plugin. I am trying to push the images using the acc bundle (astra control center) named acc.manifest.yaml. When I do that, the docker-registry is going down and restarting on its own.