# Why python package http.server only works locally?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, http, server, fileserver

when using the command

```
python -m Http.server 8000 --bind 192.168.1.105
```

the server serves the localhost only even after binding with the device address
I've tried binding with 0.0.0.0

```
python -m Http.server 8000 --bind 0.0.0.0
```

but nothing changed 
and there is no VPN running on the device 
I'm working on windows platform and trying to access the server form a mobile phone and a Linux platform 
I keep getting a message from the client's device browsers that say the address is unreachable

Comment: Are your devices both connected to same network?

Comment: @MobrineHayde yes for sure !

Comment: You may check this, it is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333400/what-can-be-the-reasons-of-connection-refused-errors/2361762