# Python Exceptions - Connection Aborted vs. Connection Refused

Tags: python, sockets, exception

What's the difference between ConnectionAbortedError and ConnectionRefusedError?

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) only specifies one is when a connection is aborted and the other when a connection is refused... not much help.

If I have a simple server and client in python and I'm using sockets how do I reproduce each exception?

Comment: Connection refused: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2333400/2864740 (search for “TCP connection refused” and “TCP connection aborted”; Python just proxies the underlying TCP network exceptions)

Comment: that opened a whole new world for me to search, many thanks