# ECONNREFUSED , I am trying to connect to my prosgres database running the app with nodemon

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, nodemon

node:internal/process/promises:246
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
errno: -61,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 5432
}

Comment: And what information of this request do you have in the logfiles from your PostgreSQL database server? And what happens when you try to connect to the database using a different client, like psql ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2333446/1333262 Check this answer for possible reasons. Also Frank's comment is relevant here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.